# How to understand relationship between Expected Value and Law of Large Numbers?

Tags: probability

For random discrete variables, like rolling a die, the more you roll it the closer you get to the expected value of 3.5 from (p)*(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) where p = 1/6.

I would like to know how to calculate the relationship between the range of expected values while rolling it n times. If I roll once, the expected value could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. If I roll infinity times, I'm expecting around 3.5. But what about all the in-betweens?

I thought at first it would be called "Variance" but that seems to be a fixed number that can be calculated apart from n. Can you help me figure out what the terminology is that I'm looking for? I'd like to calculate the "% sure-ness of reaching the expected EV" if that makes any sense.

Comment: You may be looking for the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: yours is the correct answer -- thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some confusion about the term "expected" value. By definition, the expected value is the value you will get in a large ensemble of tries. Therefore, even if you roll once, your expected value is 3.5.

The actual number you get is not the expected value. If you get a 5 from a dice row, the expected value is still 3.5.

If you row a die n times, and take their average, the expected value of the average is still 3.5 for all n. That is because if you do that experiment many times over, the average of the average you get is 3.5.

The variance is a a rough estimate of how far you can get from the expected value. The variance is not the same for all n. In the case that n goes to infinite, the variance of the average goes to zero. When n is 1, the variance is large (2.91).

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on the terminology -- I'm new to probability. However, as I stated in the question that I'm trying to figure out better terminology, I think usul did a better job ;) Thanks for helping me understand EV though